# How can I add a slash before a dollar sign in a PhpStorm template file?

Tags: phpstorm, apache-velocity

I'm trying to create a file template for PhpStorm that has a back-slash in front of a variable. This is for a json template used in magento development, but I would say that this issue is extension ambivalent:

Text in the template:

```
"Something\\${Variable_Name}\\"
```

I would like this to result in

```json
"Something\\EnteredVariable\\"
```

But this is the results in this in the generated file:

```json
"Something\EnteredVariable\\"
```

I've tried adding an extra dollar sign which results in:

```json
"Somthing\$EnteredVariable\\"
```

and extra back slash, which results in:

```json
"Something\${Variable_Name}"
```

an extra dollar sign and an extra back slash, which also results in:

```json
"Something\${Variable_Name}"
```

I couldn't find the answer in any docs. Anyone have the answer?

Comment: **A)** Can you alter your question a bit to make it more clear (at least for me)? Please show 1) what template you have right now (you have that already); 2) what you are entering; 3) what is the result you are getting and 4) what you want to get in the end. **B)** As I understand it's a File Template context and NOT a Live Template, right? If it's a file template: can you please also show more of the template (in case if context is important here -- is that a FQN here in PHP context .. or inside the string etc)

Comment: What is the target (desired result)? Is it `"Something\\EnteredVariable\\"` or something else? To get the above just add an extra double slash. E.g. `${DS}fqn = "App\\\\${Var_name}\\";` and when entering `Test` the result would be `$fqn = "App\\Test\\";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank's to [@LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone);

The answer is to add a double backslash. To get `"Something\\VanName\\"`

```
// to get "Something\\EnteredVariable\\" use
"Somthing\\\\$Variable_Name"
```